# Python: What is the fastest way to find the most repeated feature overlaping two periods of time from table A and a large table B?

Tags: python, pandas, function, numpy, procedure

There are two tables,

• Table A: User attributes

• Table B: Features starting dates

Where according to the values of CV, CU and the range of time (from - to), an user needs to be assinged a feature F from dataframe B taking into account the feature that has been in operation the greatest number of days during the user period.

For example, for user_number 1, taking his values of CV, CU and filtering those one table B (see below) he has 5 posible features: F1, F2, F3, F4 and F5).

Interpreting table B starting dates: his time range from 2022-04-04 to 2022-05-04 means he had F1 from 2022-04-04 untill 2022-04-15 (12 days) and F2 from 2022-04-16 to 2022-05-04 (19 days). So the  assinged feature should be F2 cause 19 > 12.

A:

| user_number | CV | CU | from | to |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | m | 2022-04-04 | 2022-05-04 |
| 2 | b | n | 2022-03-27 | 2022-04-27 |
| 3 | c | o | 2022-05-04 | 2022-06-27 |

B:

| Start Date | CV | CU | Feature |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-03-14 | a | m | F1 |
| 2022-04-16 | a | m | F2 |
| 2022-05-15 | a | m | F3 |
| 2022-06-13 | a | m | F4 |
| 2022-07-07 | a | m | F5 |

C:

| user_number | CV | CU | from | to | FEATURE RESULT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | m | 2022-04-04 | 2022-05-04 | F2 |
| 2 | b | n | 2022-03-27 | 2022-04-27 | F34 |
| 3 | c | o | 2022-05-04 | 2022-06-27 | F56 |

Note: This has been done in a very inefficient way subsetting multiple times inside a function iterating over rows for 4M records taking about 4 hours in a Ryzen 5 5600x with 32gb RAM.

Comment: Where did you see *2022-04-15 (12 days)*?

Comment: Counting user 1 from date which is 2022-04-04 to 2022-04-15 (when the feauture ends according to table B). The counting is inclusive, so it is the difference between the two dates plus 1.

Comment: Ok but I don't know where 2022-04-15 is in your table B

Comment: Oh no, that is because the feature F2 starts on 2022-04-16, so it means F1 ended the day before.